# How to get all manufacturers of Android devices using WURFL in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wurfl

Im starting to work with WURFL and somehow I need list of all manufacturers of Android devices . And all Android versions. I need this info based on WURFL devices database.
Should I parse wurfl.xml by myself or ...?

Comment: If you have wurlf.xml, simply parse and get whatever info you want.

Comment: I can parse it by myself but maybe there are some gem exists ?

Answer (score 3):

You can always parse the wurfl.xml file to get the information you are looking for, however you should keep in mind that it is not a complete list of every device.  The wurfl.xml file is meant to work closely with the WURFL API.

The idea is to store the minimum amount of User Agent's for the API to be able to detect the maximum amount of devices.  So while, you might not see a device in the xml file, it most likely will still be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Or use any possible Gem out there:

https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=wurfl